# Dynamics CRM: Dependency between Product and Customer fields in Case

Tags: dynamics-crm

Why "Product" filed on incident is cleared after updating the "Customer" field? There is a good reason for that?

It occurs on my development instance, on a new clean instance OnPrem and also on an Online Trial org. So, I wonder if it's a bug or a MS wanted behavior? I do not remember something like this in previous versions of CRM.

CRM Version: 8.2.2.112

Thanks

Comment: It looks like onchange event of Customer lookup clearing the Product lookup in vanilla CRM too. Not sure about business scenario & this undocumented product behavior. Shoot the question to MS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted same question and answered it after some research, on Community forum. Here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/286163